# Counting Game Issue

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make it so the program with count forwards or backwards depending on whether the start_number is smaller or bigger than the end_number. It works when the start_number is smaller, but if it's bigger, it wont work. Any idea as to why? Thanks!

```
#Challenge 4.1
#Asks the user for a beginning and ending number, then asks for the amount count by. The      program then prints the numbers 


start_number = int(input("What number would you like me to begin with?"))
end_number = int(input("What number would you like me to end with?"))
count_number = int(input("How much would you like me to count by? " +
                     "(Note: for most accurate results have me count by a number " +
                     "that divides evenly into the number you assigned me to end with.)"))








print("\ncalculating...\n")

if start_number < end_number:
   end_number += count_number
   for number in range (start_number, end_number, count_number):
      print(number)

elif end_number < start_number:
   count_number *= -1
   for number in range (end_number, start_number, count_number):
      pyprint(number)
```

Comment: it simply comes out blank. there is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly reversed the args for range.  With that fixed, 'pyprint' would be a NameError.  You also neglected to adjust stop for down counts.  Try this for both up and down.

```
start = int(input("What number would you like me to begin with?"))
stop = int(input("What number would you like me to end with?"))
step = int(input("How much would you like me to count by?"))

if stop < start:
    step *= -1
stop += step

for number in range (start, stop, step):
      print(number)
```